# Which model to use for survival analysis when there are different times of entry into the sample?

Tags: r, survival, cox-model, hazard

I have a data set containing the trades executed by many traders as follows:

```
ID       Buy(1)/Sell(0)    StartTime    EndTime      PnL
1              1               1           1          7
1              1               2           3          5
1              0               2           5          6
1              1               3           5         -4
2              1               1           3          8
2              0               2           2         -9
2              0               3           5          3
```

where `ID` is the trader's identification number, `Buy(1)/Sell(0)` indicates whether the trade was a buy or sell, for simplicity `StartTime` and `EndTime` are the day on which the trade was opened and closed, and `PnL` is the profit or loss from that trade.

My goal here is to study whether a trader closes his position earlier (i.e. duration of a trade) based on whether he has made a gain or a loss.

I am very new to the concept of hazard models. I understand the main idea behind them, but I am not sure what is the correct model to apply in my case where I have several traders, each with multiple trades that have different entry times (`StartTime`).

I would greatly appreciate any help you can provide me, with as much detail as possible.

UPDATE: How would the model specification differ if the transactions in my data are considered to be correlated? I am using R.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you interested in what *individual* traders do (eg, 'does trader 1 close his position earlier...?'), or what traders *on average* do?

Comment: I am interested in the average, but Now that you mention it, I would also like to see how individuals do. So I would like to conduct both analyses.

Comment: You will need a model w/ a random effect of trader. You can get the predicted REs for the traders to compare them, but that doesn't entail a significance test of 1 trader vs another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Cox Proportional Hazards model in R allows for late entry into the sample.

One can enter the parameters as follows:

```
cox.model <- coxph(Surv(startTime, endTime, event) ~ X + frailty(ID), data)
```

Answer (score 4):

I would have modelled this as a plain Cox model, or perhaps a Cox Frailty model.

- You do not need to worry about the timing of entry into your study when using Cox regression (unless there is time bias, which I do not notice in your description).
- You don't need the extended Cox model with start and stop intervals, just calculate the observation time (EndTime - StartTime) and enter it into Surv(**observation_time**, event).
- You should account for the repeated measurements on the same individual by either using: (i) mixed effects cox models, (ii) the *cluster* function in *coxph*.

Comment: I agree with Adam that it's easier if we assume that what we are studying is stationary in time.